# Modular exponentiation - what do I miss?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

despite searching the web, looking up similiar questions here, and checking my lecture notes, i could not find an answer to my basic problem.

I have the expression:

$$ 264^{245} ≡_p (264\ mod\ p)^{ 245\ mod\ p−1} ,\ p=83 $$

I do not know why i am allowed to pull the mod into the exponent and base. Would someone explain that to me, steer me towards a site, or theorem?

Comment: Look up Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: I already did, i still do not see how that can be applied in connection to the mod in the base, and exponent.

Comment: See [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) in the first dupe for the law for reducing the exponent mod the period of the power, and see the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) in the second dupe for the law for reducing the base, e.g. combining $\bmod n\!:\ a^k\equiv (a\bmod n)^{k\bmod \phi}\,$ if $\,a^{\phi}\equiv 1,\,$ e.g. if $\,\phi = \phi(n),\ (a,n)\!=\!1\ \ $

Comment: If you seek proofs using the language of ring theory and group theory (vs. congruences) see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3910465/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1871703/242)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The modular calculations in the base and the exponent are valid for different reasons.

To calculate
$$
a^b \pmod{83}
$$
you can replace $a$ with its remainder $\pmod{83}$. That works whether or not $83$ is prime (which it is).

Since $83$ is prime, Fermat's little theorem says
$$
a^{82} \equiv 1 \pmod{83}
$$
(when $a$ is not a multiple of $83$)
so if you calculate $b$ modulo $82$ as
$$
b =   82q+ r
$$
then
$$
a^b \equiv a^{82q+ r} \equiv (a^{82})^q a^r \equiv a^r \pmod{83} .
$$

Note: I suspect this question is a duplicate on MSE. I couldn't find a good link, so I wrote this answer.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score -1):

The square root of $83$ is a little over $9$, so after trying to divide $83$ by $2,3,5$ and $7$ - it's a prime number.

The reason you can pull the $\text{mod}$ into the base is because reducing $\mod n$ for any positive integer $n$ is a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.  As a result, multiplying two integers and then reducing them gives the same result as first reducing each, doing the multiplication and reducing again.  (Same for addition BTW.)

The reason you can pull the $\mod (p-1)$ into the **exponent** for a **prime** $p$ is because the set of non-zero residues $\mod p$ is an abelian group under multiplication of size $p-1$.  It is in fact a cyclic group - though that's not important for this.  The (multiplicative) order of any element in it is divisible by $p-1$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the specific values don't matter here, so long as $p=83$ is prime. As such, I'm going to let $a=264$ and $n=245$.

Multiplication of (nonzero) integers modulo a prime $p$ forms a group of order $p-1$, so:
$$
a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p
$$
(This is one multiplication by $a$ away from the usual statement of Fermat's Little Theorem, and so we could have used that fact as well).

So, if we start with the expression $a^{n} \mod p$, we can multiply by $a^{p-1}$ as many times as we wish without changing the value, since it is congruent to the multiplicative identity, $1$. So, we get:
$$
a^{n} \equiv a^{n}(a^{p-1})^k\equiv a^{n + k(p-1)}\mod p
$$
Since $k$ can be anything, this means that $a^n$ is congruent modulo $p$ to all $a^N$, where $N=n+k(p-1)$. The possible values of $N$ are, by definition, the numbers congruent to $n$ modulo $p-1$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).